# javascript: passing basic math operations to function

Tags: javascript, function, math

I am programming a calculator that takes a string representing a calculation and outputs the result (like the `eval` function).
At some point in my code I define the meaning of the different operations like this:

```
const _ops = [
    [
        ["^", (a, b) => (+a) ** +b],
    ],
    [
        ["*", (a, b) => +a * +b],
        ["/", (a, b) => +a / +b],
        ["%", (a, b) => +a % +b],
    ],
    [
        ["+", (a, b) => +a + +b],
        ["-", (a, b) => +a - +b],
    ],
];
```

As you can see I am repeating the function part every time while only one character changes (except for the first time...)

```
(a, b) => +a ${operation} +b
```

Do you have any idea how I could do this without repeating the function declaration every time?

PS: If you can think of a better title, feel free to change it.

Comment: That's probably the best way to go in JavaScript. The only alternative would be to use `eval()` and that has its own problems.

Comment: I agree, there isn't really any way to simplify it without `eval`. BTW, I would use an object rather than an array, e.g. `{"*": (a, b) => +a * +b, "/": (a, b) => +a / +b, ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` would look kind of like this.

```
const dynamicCalculation = (a ,b, operator) => {
   if (operator === "^") operator = "**"

   return eval("${+a} ${operator} ${+b}")
}
```

usage:

```
dynamicCalculation(1,2,"+") // => 3
dynamicCalculation(1,2,"-") // => -1
dynamicCalculation(1,2,"*") // => 2
```

switch:

```
const dynamicCalculation = (a ,b, operator) => {
    let output;
    switch(operator){
       case "+":
           output = a + b;
           break;
       case "-":
           output = a - b;
           break;
       case "*":
           output = a * b;
           break;
       case "/":
           output = a / b;
           break;
       case "^":
           output = a ** b;
           break;
       case "%":
           output = a % b;
           break;
    }

    return output
}
```

Comment: I am basically wrote the calculator to avoid eval - my question was how to not repeat myself by writing the full function every time

Comment: the other way would be to use a switch statement but its not much better

Comment: How would a switch statement avoid the repetition?

Comment: the switch wouldnt avoid repetition but it would avoid the eval

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in JavaScript without `eval`. This is because there is no way to treat an operator as a function. This is not the case e.g. in Haskell, where `(*)` represents the multiplication function, which you can carry around as a value, apply a value to get a partially-applied operator, and apply another value to get the result.